# Multiple ngx-bootstrap modals in one component(Angular) css styles conflict

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-modal

I have two modals in one component in Angular:

```
 <button type="button" button class="add" (click)="openModal()">Dodaj</button>

<div class="jokes">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 joke" *ngFor="let joke of jokes">
    <div class="category">
      kategoria: <span>{{ getCategoryName(joke.category) }} </span>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      {{joke.content}}
    </div>
    <button class="delete" (click)="openConfirmModal(confirmModal, joke.id)">Usuń</button>
  </div>
</div>
<ng-template #modalTemplate>
  <app-modal [modalRef]="modalRef" (jokeAdded)="handleJokeAdded($event)" class="add-modal"></app-modal>
</ng-template>
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert" [hidden]="!jokeAdded">
  Żart został dodany!
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" (click)="hide()" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>

<ng-template #confirmModal class="confirm-window">
  <div class="modal-body text-center confirm-modal">
    <p>Czy napewno chcesz usunąć wybrany żart?</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="confirmDelete()">Tak</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="decline()">Nie</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

I have problem with styling. I would like to confirm window just be on top and have different styles than other modal. I tried to add new id/classes or put second modal in another div and then styling. But only thing that works is '.modal-content' class, so the modals looks similar. Any help ?  Here's my css :

```
    .modal-content{
    width: 600px;
    height: 473px;
    margin-top: 255px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I have correctly understood what you want to achieve, but you can add your own CSS classes to modals, [when opening it in a Component/TypeScript file.](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/modals?tab=overview#service-custom-css-class)
Something like this:

```
  openConfirmModal(template: TemplateRef<any>, jokeId:number) {
    ...
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(
      template,
      Object.assign({}, { class: 'confirm-modal' })
    );
  }
```

It seem like this arent component-scoped classes so you would have to define them in global css file or set view encapsulation to none in component.